# Protégé object property restrictions

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, restriction

I defined an object property  `"is_part_of"` where **the domain is Flight** and **the range is Airline**; i want to define the following restriction

> "flight is_part_of Airline exactly 1 Airline "

I tried  `is_part_of only Airline exactly 1 Airline` 
but it doesn't work.
I think that the poblem is with `exactly 1 Airline` but i don't manage to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `Airline` to appear twice.

`Flight subClassOf is_part_of exactly 1 Airline`

`is_part_of exactly 1 Airline` is the class expression you're after.

Comment: Why the reasoner don't catch exception if a Flight instance has not an object property is_part_of?

Comment: Open world assumption. The reasoner knows there must be one, but it might not be stated which value it has. It becomes a contradiction only if the instance is also inferred to have no property or two - or more - properties.

Comment: Can you give me an example, I haven't understand. I would have a contradiction if an instance of Flight has not some object property is_part_of

Comment: You would not. Reasoning in owl works with the assumption that not all facts are known. For example, we know spiders have eight legs - by definition. If we have an instance of spider, with no other information, we do not know anything about its legs, but we know there are eight of them. We would have a contradiction only if the spider was also a member of a class that said 'six legs' - for example, an instance of spider and insect would be a contradiction. Absence of evidence does not imply evidence of absence.

Comment: So I can't determine an instance of a particular class that has not an object property defined?

Comment: If you're thinking of negation as failure, no, it cannot be applied in OWL